# Normalization: different approach

Tags: probability, neural-networks, normalization

Today I had a discussion about the right way to normalize data, especially image data. The standard approach, as found in many tutorials etc., seems to be following.  For example, the data has a range of integer values from $k = 0, ..., 255$ (e.g. uint8 value for each channel or grayscale in image encoding) with $N=256$ values. We form the scaled values:

$$x = \frac{k}{N-1} \quad \quad \rightarrow \quad \quad x = 0, \tfrac{1}{N-1}, ..., \tfrac{N-2}{N-1}, 1.$$

These value are on a scale between zero and one.  After processing the $x$ values by a neural network for example, the processed values $\hat{x}$ get transformed back to $\hat{k} = \hat{x} \cdot (N-1)$ and then **rounded to the nearest integer**.  This gives us processed values for the $k$ values.

---

**Problem with this procedure:** I believe that this procedure leads to a systematic statistical distortion.  For example, when $N=4$, the scaled values are $x = 0, \tfrac{1}{3}, \tfrac{2}{3}, 1$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$.  We process these scaled values to some processed values $\hat{x}$ and then we convert these back to processed values of $k$ via rounding, so that:

$$\hat{k} = \hat{k}(\hat{x}) = \begin{cases} 
0 & & \text{for }\hat{x} \in [0, \tfrac{1}{6}), \\
1 & & \text{for }\hat{x} \in [\tfrac{1}{6}, \tfrac{3}{6}), \\
2 & & \text{for }\hat{x} \in [\tfrac{3}{6}, \tfrac{5}{6}), \\
3 & & \text{for }\hat{x} \in [\tfrac{5}{6}, 1]. \\
\end{cases}$$

Now, let's assume, that the processed values $\hat{x}$ are uniformly distributed.  Then the probabilities of the corresponding values of $\hat{k}$ do not reflect the originally uniformly distributed x values.

---

**My proposed solution:** Because of this problem, my proposal is to scale the values as:

$$x = \frac{k + \tfrac{1}{2}}{N} \quad \quad \rightarrow \quad \quad x = \tfrac{1}{2N}, \tfrac{3}{2N}, ..., \tfrac{2N-3}{2N}, \tfrac{2N-1}{2N}.$$

By this method, the scaled values get placed in the midpoints of $N$ equal intervals, and we take $\hat{k} = \hat{x} \cdot N - \tfrac{1}{2}$ and then round to the nearest integer to get back the processed values of $k$.  (Since $1 \cdot N - \tfrac{1}{2}$ gets rounded up to $N$, which is out of the range of allowable values, we process this case separately.)  The transformation back to integer values of $\hat{k}$ then leads to equal probabilities for all values in the example above.

**My question:** In my opinion, this seems to be much more consistent in a statistal sense.  So my question is, what do you think about it, and why is the first approach (dividing by $N-1$) so common?

Comment: I have made major edits to your question to put the mathematics in Latex notation, to make it clearer.  I have also made major edits to your phrasing of the question to fix grammatical issues and make the question clearer.  Can you please review this edit to make sure it correctly encapsulates your question.

Comment: Well, thank you very much! As far as I can see, everything is "translated" correct. I'm not a native english speaker, sorry for the bad grammar!